# Optimizing drawLayer animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, quartz-graphics

I have a game where I draw between 4 and 5 large circles on a UIView and then spin them. This is all done via the `drawLayer:inContext:` method.

While it works, it is very inefficient, and uses up 100% of the CPU; 5 circles taking up 100% of the CPU?! That's outrageous! I must be approaching this wrong.

How can I efficiently animate drawn paths in Objective-C so that the CPU usage is not so high? Am I just simply not supposed to animate this way? If so, how can I properly animate a shape that will have to change?

---

To give you a bit more of an idea of what I'm trying to do here, there are 5 rings that are displayed on the screen. Each of these has a gap in it where the user will attempt to escape. The rings will be constantly collapsing to the center of the screen, but the line width and the gap size (along the circumference) will always be the same.

That is why I'm not just doing this with CGAffineTransforms. The rings need to be constantly re-drawn as their radii shrink.

---

Here is the code that I am using:

```
const float ringThickness = 20;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame displayMode:(BOOL)mode
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        playMode = mode;

        [self.layer setContentsScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];

        rings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        if(mode)
        {
            //Add rings
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                [rings addObject:[@{@"radius" : @(100+ 40 * i + 5*powf(i, 2)), @"gapCenter" : @(randomFloat(0, 2 * M_PI)), @"direction" : @(i % 2)} mutableCopy]];
            }

            gapSize = 250;

            autoplay = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/60.0 target:self selector:@selector(timer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        }

        [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    return self;
} 

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapButt);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, ringThickness);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

    for(int i = 0; i < rings.count; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* ring = rings[i];

        float radius = [ring[@"radius"] floatValue];
        float brightness = 120 / radius;
        brightness = (brightness > 1) ? 1 : brightness;

        if(playMode)
            brightness /= 2;

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:(153.0/255) blue:(151.0/255) alpha:brightness].CGColor);

        float gapCenter = [ring[@"gapCenter"] floatValue];
        float cc = 2 * M_PI * radius;
        float gapWidth = gapSize / cc * 360;
        float gapStart = gapCenter + (gapWidth / 360.0 * M_PI);

        CGContextAddArc(ctx, sw()/2, sh()/2, radius, gapStart, gapStart + (2 * M_PI) - (gapWidth / 360.0 * M_PI), 0);
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

        if(playMode)
        {
            //Autoplay
            if([ring[@"direction"] boolValue])
            {
                ring[@"gapCenter"] = @(gapCenter + 0.005 * M_PI);
            }
            else
            {
                ring[@"gapCenter"] = @(gapCenter - 0.005 * M_PI);
            }

        }
    }
}

- (void)timer
{
    [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Can someone please steer me in the right direction? This is one piece of ObjC that I still don't understand very well.

Comment: Why don't you use `CAShapeLayer`?

Comment: @KurtRevis Like I said, these are uncharted waters for me. I've never used a CAShapeLayer before. Can you please walk me through a little bit on how I could do this with a CAShapeLayer?

Comment: @KurtRevis I was able to figure it out. Thanks for the direction! Now it's using about 4% of my CPU, which is awesome.